# Mariadb won't start (can't change dir, errcode 13: permission denied)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

I moved my MariaDB database to `/media/user/extdrive1/mysql`, updated the conf files, and changed `chown` for the drive to 7777 for user mysql.mysql. Despite all this, `sudo systemctl start mysqld` fails, and if I check the syslog, it returns a errcode 13: Permission Denied to `/media/user/extdrive1/mysql`.

Unsure what else to try; apparmor mysql file is empty.

EDIT (permissions):

```
/media/user/extdrive1/mysql:
total 110628
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 20:51 .
drwsrwsrwt 4 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:15 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    16384 May  2 00:40 aria_log.00000001
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql       52 May  2 00:40 aria_log_control
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 debian-10.1.flag
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 12582912 May  2 20:51 ibdata1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 May  2 20:51 ib_logfile0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 May  2 00:40 ib_logfile1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 multi-master.info
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:40 mysql
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 mysql.sock
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:40 performance_schema

/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/mysql:
total 1096
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 .
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2110 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2602 May  2 00:40 column_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 column_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 column_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2677 May  2 00:40 db.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 db.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 db.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3683 May  2 00:40 event.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 event.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 event.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1582 May  2 00:40 func.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 func.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 func.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql     35 May  2 00:40 general_log.CSM
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 general_log.CSV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    804 May  2 00:40 general_log.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 gtid_slave_pos.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 gtid_slave_pos.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1706 May  2 00:40 help_category.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1092 May  2 00:40 help_category.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3072 May  2 00:40 help_category.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1638 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  91408 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  16384 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    970 May  2 00:40 help_relation.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   9252 May  2 00:40 help_relation.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  19456 May  2 00:40 help_relation.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1776 May  2 00:40 help_topic.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 405476 May  2 00:40 help_topic.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  20480 May  2 00:40 help_topic.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1897 May  2 00:40 host.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 host.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 host.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1629 May  2 00:40 index_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 index_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 index_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4998 May  2 00:40 innodb_index_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 innodb_index_stats.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1503 May  2 00:40 innodb_table_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 innodb_table_stats.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1518 May  2 00:40 plugin.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 plugin.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 plugin.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3418 May  2 00:40 proc.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1144 May  2 00:40 proc.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 proc.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2874 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2839 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1269 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  10240 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1661 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2703 May  2 00:40 servers.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 servers.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 servers.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql     35 May  2 00:40 slow_log.CSM
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 slow_log.CSV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2374 May  2 00:40 slow_log.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2957 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1374 May  2 00:40 table_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 table_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 table_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    973 May  2 00:40 time_zone.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    971 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1146 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1013 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1079 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3191 May  2 00:40 user.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    176 May  2 00:40 user.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 user.MYI

/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/performance_schema:
total 12
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 May  2 00:40 .
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql 4096 May  2 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   61 May  2 00:40 db.opt

/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/:
total 110628
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 20:51 .
drwsrwsrwt 4 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:15 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    16384 May  2 00:40 aria_log.00000001
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql       52 May  2 00:40 aria_log_control
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 debian-10.1.flag
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 12582912 May  2 20:51 ibdata1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 May  2 20:51 ib_logfile0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 May  2 00:40 ib_logfile1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 multi-master.info
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:40 mysql
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 mysql.sock
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:40 performance_schema

/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/mysql:
total 1096
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 .
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2110 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2602 May  2 00:40 column_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 column_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 column_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2677 May  2 00:40 db.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 db.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 db.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3683 May  2 00:40 event.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 event.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 event.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1582 May  2 00:40 func.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 func.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 func.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql     35 May  2 00:40 general_log.CSM
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 general_log.CSV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    804 May  2 00:40 general_log.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 gtid_slave_pos.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 gtid_slave_pos.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1706 May  2 00:40 help_category.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1092 May  2 00:40 help_category.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3072 May  2 00:40 help_category.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1638 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  91408 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  16384 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    970 May  2 00:40 help_relation.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   9252 May  2 00:40 help_relation.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  19456 May  2 00:40 help_relation.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1776 May  2 00:40 help_topic.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 405476 May  2 00:40 help_topic.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  20480 May  2 00:40 help_topic.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1897 May  2 00:40 host.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 host.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 host.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1629 May  2 00:40 index_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 index_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 index_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4998 May  2 00:40 innodb_index_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 innodb_index_stats.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1503 May  2 00:40 innodb_table_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 innodb_table_stats.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1518 May  2 00:40 plugin.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 plugin.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 plugin.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3418 May  2 00:40 proc.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1144 May  2 00:40 proc.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 proc.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2874 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2839 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1269 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  10240 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1661 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2703 May  2 00:40 servers.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 servers.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 servers.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql     35 May  2 00:40 slow_log.CSM
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 slow_log.CSV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2374 May  2 00:40 slow_log.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2957 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1374 May  2 00:40 table_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 table_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 table_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    973 May  2 00:40 time_zone.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    971 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1146 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1013 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1079 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3191 May  2 00:40 user.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    176 May  2 00:40 user.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 user.MYI

/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/performance_schema:
total 12
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 May  2 00:40 .
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql 4096 May  2 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   61 May  2 00:40 db.opt

mysql:
total 110628
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 20:51 .
drwsrwsrwt 4 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:15 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    16384 May  2 00:40 aria_log.00000001
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql       52 May  2 00:40 aria_log_control
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 debian-10.1.flag
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 12582912 May  2 20:51 ibdata1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 May  2 20:51 ib_logfile0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 May  2 00:40 ib_logfile1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 multi-master.info
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:40 mysql
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 May  2 00:40 mysql.sock
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql     4096 May  2 00:40 performance_schema

mysql/mysql:
total 1096
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 .
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2110 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 columns_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2602 May  2 00:40 column_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 column_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 column_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2677 May  2 00:40 db.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 db.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 db.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3683 May  2 00:40 event.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 event.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 event.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1582 May  2 00:40 func.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 func.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 func.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql     35 May  2 00:40 general_log.CSM
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 general_log.CSV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    804 May  2 00:40 general_log.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 gtid_slave_pos.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 gtid_slave_pos.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1706 May  2 00:40 help_category.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1092 May  2 00:40 help_category.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3072 May  2 00:40 help_category.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1638 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  91408 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  16384 May  2 00:40 help_keyword.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    970 May  2 00:40 help_relation.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   9252 May  2 00:40 help_relation.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  19456 May  2 00:40 help_relation.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1776 May  2 00:40 help_topic.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 405476 May  2 00:40 help_topic.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  20480 May  2 00:40 help_topic.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1897 May  2 00:40 host.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 host.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 host.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1629 May  2 00:40 index_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 index_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 index_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4998 May  2 00:40 innodb_index_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 innodb_index_stats.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1503 May  2 00:40 innodb_table_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  98304 May  2 00:40 innodb_table_stats.ibd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1518 May  2 00:40 plugin.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 plugin.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 plugin.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3418 May  2 00:40 proc.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1144 May  2 00:40 proc.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 proc.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2874 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 procs_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2839 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1269 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  10240 May  2 00:40 proxies_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1661 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 roles_mapping.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2703 May  2 00:40 servers.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 servers.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 servers.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql     35 May  2 00:40 slow_log.CSM
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 slow_log.CSV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2374 May  2 00:40 slow_log.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2957 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 tables_priv.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1374 May  2 00:40 table_stats.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 table_stats.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   2048 May  2 00:40 table_stats.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    973 May  2 00:40 time_zone.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    971 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_leap_second.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1146 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_name.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1013 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1079 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql      0 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   1024 May  2 00:40 time_zone_transition_type.MYI
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   3191 May  2 00:40 user.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    176 May  2 00:40 user.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   4096 May  2 00:40 user.MYI

mysql/performance_schema:
total 12
drwsrwsrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 May  2 00:40 .
drwsrwsrwx 4 mysql mysql 4096 May  2 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   61 May  2 00:40 db.opt
```

And here's the MariaDB config file:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]
datadir=/media/user/extdrive1/mysql
socket=/media/user/extdrive1/mysql.sock

[client]
port=3306
socket=/media/user/extdrive1/mysql.sock
```

ps aux | grep mysql returns this:

`user    21359  0.0  0.0   4772   568 pts/2    S+   02:27   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql`

Comment: Please check and paste if you still have issues starting it:    
    ls -la path/mysql/
    tail path/mysql/error.log
    chown -R mysql path/mysql/

Comment: @ninjabber see above!

Comment: now please
`cat path/my.cnf`
`ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: @ninjabber Updated!

Comment: `190504 03:04:16 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.`
`190504 03:04:16 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /media/user/extdrive1/mysql`

Comment: Done, still permission denied. :/

Comment: @ninjabber its obviously not a mysql user permission so please stop with the wild ass guessing on `skip-grant-tarbles`. Chmod changes like a webdeveloper don't help things either. Take a look at the permission hierarchy `name -i /media/user/extdrive1/mysql` you'll see a missing execute permission missing on a directory. Alternately its a selinux (unlinkely on what I assume is Ubuntu/Debian), or systemd constraint (few good links are [in the kb on thing to look if it doesn't start](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start))

Comment: It’ll just be a missing permission on one of the directories in the hierarchy, as @danblack said

Comment: @ninjabber can you delete your comments please? You were going down the wrong rabbit hole, clearly not seeing the obvious Unix error

Comment: Check permissions for directories /, /media/, /media/user/, and /media/user/extdrive1/ -- they need to have at least `r` and `x` for "others".

Comment: Thanks all -- it was a hierarchy permissions issue. A `chmod -R 777 /media` fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the @danblack, @Philᵀᴹ, and @rick-james mentioned in the comments, this was a   permissions hierarchy issue. While `/media/user/extdrive1` and `media/user/extdrive1/mysql` both had the right permissions, mysql could not get to the folders it had permission to access because of permissions restrictions on `/media` and `/media/user`.

Thanks for your help, everyone!